# PHP como agregar funcion add_action en una tabla

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, table

estoy atorado modificando una página de producto de Woocommerce en Wordpress porque quiero ordenar la información que muestra y ponerla en una tabla

por ejemplo:

Precio USD | Precio MXN | Cantidad

pero no puedo poner dentro de la tabla la funcion add_action

esto es lo que tengo:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_custom_content', 32 );

function woocommerce_template_custom_content(){

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "  <th>Precio USD</th>";
echo "  <th>Precio MXN</th>";
echo "  <th>Cantidad</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>. add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 1); .</td>";
echo "<td> $ 0.00 MXN</td>";
echo "<td> Cantidad 1 </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>"; 


}
```

Lo tengo en functions.php

Ayuda porfa!!!! que estoy haciendo mal?, o como se debe de llamar a esta función? de antemano muchas gracias a todos!!!!

Answer (score 0):

[`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) se usa para asignar una función a un evento y siempre devuelve verdadero, por eso aparece `1` en la tabla.

Entonces debes crear la función para que sea ejecutada cuando se lanza el evento:

```
add_action( 'evento', 'nombre_funcion', 1, [$params]);
```

Donde `$params` es la cantidad de parámetros que debe recibir la función, si es que los va a recibir.

Cuando necesites que se ejecute incluyes el siguiente código:

```
do_action('evento', [$param1, $param2, ... $paramX]);
```

Estás agregando `add_action(...)` como cadena, sin llamar realmente a la función:

```
echo "<td>. add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 1); .</td>";
```

Tienes cerrar las comillas y agregar punto entre cada elemento que quieras concatenar:
`"inicio" . funcion('parametros') . "fin de cadena";`

Función corregida, lanzando el evento:

```
function woocommerce_template_custom_content(){
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "  <th>Precio USD</th>";
    echo "  <th>Precio MXN</th>";
    echo "  <th>Cantidad</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    // do_action, en vez de add_action
    echo "<td>" . do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary') . "</td>";
    echo "<td> $ 0.00 MXN</td>";
    echo "<td> Cantidad 1 </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>"; 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Triby de verdad no sabes como agradezco tu tiempo para responderme, ya puse el codigo como me indicaste y entendi el error que estaba cometiendo, sin embargo al arrojar el resultado en la tabla (cosa que no tengo problema, la tabla esta perfecta) me pone solo un 1, y cambio el hook y sigue arrojando siempre 1

Comment: Revisa la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Gracias @Triby ahora me aparece en blanco el campo, entiendo que con esto ya llance el evento pero lo que quiero es que me muestre la funcion dentro del campo, eso es lo que no se como llamarlo para que lo traiga y lo muestre y en el do_action solo estamos pidiendo el evento pero no la funcion 'woocommerce_template_single_price'

Comment: ¿Qué tienes en la función `woocommerce_template_custom_content`? Debería devolver algún contenido, no solo realizar consultas.